# IIS virtual directory home different than Apache

Tags: apache, iis, virtual-directory, home-directory

I have a site I developed on a WAMP server in house, and is hosted offsite (presumably on an Apache server). The site was created in the root directory of the WAMP server (C:\wamp\www). I'm now trying to move the in house development site onto a Windows Home Server v1 box (essentially a Server 2003 machine running IIS 6). I'm trying to not have two different versions of the site: one for in house (on IIS), and one for hosting offsite (on Apache).

On the WHS machine, I have a virtual directory `<sitename>` located at:

```
c:/inetpub/<sitename>
```

I can access it on the server at:

```
Localhost/<sitename>
```

and from anywhere on the LAN at:

```
<ServerName>/<sitename>
```

When I initially wrote the site, I used the ../ declaration for almost every file, 
path, directory, and PHP include files. This works fine on the WAMP server and on the 
offsite host. But, when I moved the site into the virtual directory `<sitename>`, it 
fails on the IIS server.

All such ../ references point to the server root:

`<ServerName>/`

rather than site home:

```
<ServerName>/<sitename>
```

Presumably, I could move the site into the 'root' directory: c:/inetpub/wwwroot, but
Windows Home Server uses this for something else.

I could change every reference from ../ to `../<sitename>/`, but that would mean having 2 
different sites to maintain, one for in house and one for offsite.

So, my questions are ...

1. Is there any way to declare that the virtual directory `c:/inetpub/<sitename>`
   is the home or root directory for this single site? Is there a configuration 
   in IIS that will do this *for this one virtual directory*, and not upset the other
   sites hosted on this server?

If not;

1. Can someone point me to some other way to rewrite the site in order
   to have it run  on *both* Apache and IIS 6 with no/minimal
   alterations for the two different servers?

I have been searching for over a week on this. All of the solutions that I have found are specific to either Apache or IIS, but won't work in both.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's a -possible- answer ...

I changed every `../` to a PHP include statement, calling a file I named `SiteBase.txt`.

On the IIS server, SiteBase.txt consists of a single line: `http://<ServerName>/<sitename>/`.

On the WAMP server, SiteBase.txt consists of a single line: `../`

This way, I only have to change this one file when I move the site from my development server to the production server. A bit Brute-Force, but it seems to be working.

Does anyone see a problem with this?

Thanks!